# Rename last column in a dataframe passed along in method chain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I rename the last column in a dataframe, that was passed along in a method chain? Think about the following example (the real use case is more complex). How can the rename function refer to the dataframe that it processes (which is different from the "table" dataframe? Is there something like the following? Unfortunately "self" does not exist.

```
result = table.iloc[:,2:-1].rename(columns={self.columns[-1]: "Text"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pipe()`:

```
result = table.iloc[:,2:-1].pipe(lambda df: df.rename(columns={df.columns[-1]: "Text"}))
```

Comment: @Wen-Ben that should not be my fault. You try to do things in a chain, you should know the risk (or you assumed that would not be the case).

Comment: You guys are so fast, that I have to wait for another 4 minutes until I can accept an answer :-)

Comment: @IanS if the `iloc` part produces a dataframe with no columns, the rename part will not work. But I reply that it is the engineering trade off if you want to do it in a chain.

Comment: @adrtam I agree with you but I feel like Wen-Ben is making a different point (and at this point I think he's wrong, but it depends on how you interpret the original question).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can just do the following:

```
result = table.iloc[:,2:-1]
result.columns = result.columns[:-1] + ["Text"]
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the chain.